# Is there an alternative to this command, that can be run on a windows machine?

Tags: php, windows, command-line, mdns

I have written a PHP script which runs this command in a shell:

```
dns-sd -B _roomcast-capi._tcp
```

The expected result is something containing the 'Instance Name', like this:

```
Browsing for _roomcast-capi._tcp
DATE: ---Tue 02 Apr 2019---
16:22:49.344  ...STARTING...
Timestamp     A/R    Flags  if Domain               Service Type         Instance Name
16:22:49.345  Add        3   5 local.               _roomcast-capi._tcp. roomcast-d36aa71c4b694059811ebf105537f91e
16:22:49.345  Add        2   6 local.               _roomcast-capi._tcp. roomcast-d36aa71c4b694059811ebf105537f91e
```

It is working fine when i am on my OSx machine, but from my research it will probably not have the same result when i try it on my windows PC - is this correct?

If this is the case, then my question is this: Are there any alternative commands that i can run on windows, that will return a similar result to the command above?

Comment: I would recommend you look into a minimalist linux docker container to run your PHP applications in

Comment: I briefly looked at this as an option, but i think we need a simpler solution than this. Although my gut is telling me that there isn't one out there..

Comment: Having a consistent easily modifiable working environment will help you in the long run anyway

Comment: This is for a very small API someone will be using for a temp job - so no need to invest in the long run. I completely agree with you that it would be more beneficial, but in this particular case i need to find a simpler solution that i can roll out ASAP

Comment: Well, if the person working on it installs docker, they can just up an ubuntu image. Shouldn't be much setup, that's the only solution to your problem I can think of outside of using a VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the dns-sd command is part of the Bonjour service pack, so this explains why it is working on OSx and not windows.

The simple solution was to install Bonjour on my windows machine, and the dns-sd command started working in the command line.